# Matrix.Multiply in C#, how does it work?

Tags: c#, winforms, matrix, matrix-multiplication

So, I found a documentation about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.multiply(v=vs.110).aspx), but I didn't find how it works, like this example:

```
private void multiplicationExample()
{

    Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30);
    Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12);

    // matrixResult is equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
    Matrix matrixResult = Matrix.Multiply(matrix1, matrix2);

    // matrixResult2 is also
    // equal to (70,100,150,220,240,352) 
    Matrix matrixResult2 = matrix1 * matrix2;
}
```

My question is, what dimension does this matrix have? Like 3x2 or 2x3? How to read the Matrix structure in this method? How to determine the dimension?

Thank you before.

Comment: Please note, that System.Windows.Media.Matrix is a limited data type, designed for [one special purpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx): 'Represents a 3x3 affine transformation matrix used for transformations in 2-D space.' If you want perform general mathematic matrix calculations, search for a more appropriate type, maybe outside of the .NET framework.

Comment: If you would follow appropriate link in documentation for extra information, you would have find all necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

It is 2x2 with offsetX 
 Look here 
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx 
  and here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix.offsetx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: so, this multiplication method cannot be a dynamic? only for 2x2 right?

Thank you for the info :D

Comment: There is a 4x4 matrix in System.Numerics i think https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.numerics.matrix4x4(v=vs.111).aspx  but don't know of a general matrix implementation in the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do matrix arithmetic, I have recently started using the [Accord](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Math_Matrix.htm) package (available via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Accord/)). It works just fine for me.